# A way to put the facebook "feed" pop up inside a jquery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, facebook

Is there a way to put the facebook feed pop up (that publishes to your wall) inside a jquery dialog box?  This is the code I have, which will have the dialog box and feed come up as different pop ups:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false, height: 250, width: 500, modal: true, dialogCLass: 'main-dialog-class'});

  $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );

                       $.getJSON(
                                 "/like_artist.php", // The server URL
                                 { artist_id : $(this).data('artist_id') }, // Data you want to pass to the server.
                                 function(json) {

                                    var text = '';
                                    text = 'You want ' +  json[1] + ' to play a show in your town!  Increase the chances that ' + json[1] + ' comes through your area on tour by alerting your friends!';
                                    $('#dialog-modal').text(text);

                                       FB.ui({
                                       method: 'feed'
                                       });

                                    alert(json[1]);
                                 }// The function to call on completion.
                                 );


        });

  });
</script>
```

Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) by calling it per URL in a “fake popup”, if you open it inside an iframe in your jQuery dialog box.

(Give it an URL on your site as `return_uri`, that will execute a piece of JavaScript code in the iframe’s parent window, that will close the dialog again or something.)

Although, this will only work if the user is already logged in to Facebook (you might want to use [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to determine that beforehand) – because if not, Facebook will redirect to the Auth dialog, and that can not be shown in any kind of frame, it has to be opened at the top level window.